# Unable to find a specification for GooglePlaces

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) tutorial, however when I run

```
pod install
```

in step 2 part 6 I get the error

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `GooglePlaces`
```

Any idea on why this might be happening?

UPDATE:
Podfile looks like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'YOUR_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME_HERE' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
```

With `YOUR_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME_HERE` changed to my target name.

Comment: its quatation problem I think try pod 'GooglePlaces'  .. copy and paste that lines from docs to your podfile ... dont write it yourself

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Didn't work : ( Same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seemed to have worked for me:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
target 'WhatsOpen' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlacesAPI'
end
```

This was after trying Nilesh Jha's answer.

It also said
`[!] GooglePlaces has been deprecated in favor of GooglePlacesAPI`
So I replaced 'GooglePlaces' with 'GooglePlacesAPI' and it seems satisfied.

Comment: Beware, `GooglePlacesAPI` is not a Google framework. While upgrading from old monolithic `GoogleMaps` to `GooglePlaces` I started down this road too and none of my source was compatible.

Answer (score 1):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `GooglePlacesAPI` if you're expecting source compatibility with older code that used the `GoogleMaps` pod. That one's a 3rd party framework, not Google's.

Run `pod repo update` and then try `pod install` again. Also, I added a version to make the line `pod 'GooglePlaces', '~> 2.0'`, but I don't know if that's required.