# googlePlaces api giving wrong values after parsing

Tags: swift, google-places-api

`GooglePlaces.placeDetails` api giving wrong result after parsing. `Lat` `long` returns same but actually not if we hit API on browser but after parsing gets wrong.

```
GooglePlaces.placeDetails(forPlaceID: location.locationID, extensions: nil, language: nil) { (response, error) in

    print("lat", response!.result!.geometryLocation!.latitude)
    print("long",  response!.result!.geometryLocation!.longitude)

    location.locationLat = String(response!.result!.geometryLocation!.latitude)
    location.locationLong = String(response!.result!.geometryLocation!.longitude)
    self.moveToFirstScreen(location)
}
```

> `response!.result!.geometryLocation!.longitude` giving same value as latitude.

Please guide.

Update: response print

response: Optional(GooglePlaces.GooglePlaces.PlaceDetailsResponse(status: Optional(GooglePlaces.GoogleMapsService.StatusCode.OK), errorMessage: nil, result: Optional(GooglePlaces.GooglePlaces.PlaceDetailsResponse.Result(addressComponents: [GooglePlaces.GooglePlaces.PlaceDetailsResponse.Result.AddressComponent(types: ["country", "political"], longName: Optional("Sweden"), shortName: Optional("SE"))], formattedAddress: Optional("Sweden"), formattedPhoneNumber: nil, geometryLocation: Optional(GooglePlaces.GoogleMapsService.LocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 60.128161000000013, longitude: 60.128161000000013)), icon: Optional(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png), internationalPhoneNumber: nil, name: Optional("Sweden"), openingHours: nil, permanentlyClosed: false, photos: [GooglePlaces.GooglePlaces.PlaceDetailsResponse.Result.Photo(photoReference: Optional("CoQBdwAAADUoXSF59OQfAt8YLQ_aJ3aRAZ8gdgzHEw_y7Dp_malOm8OL_iwJA_JMEhb17Bx8dHgoeUYuPp-2Tnk8W23Zy9gWfadRWDXGfs2obbNbadpDNb3zOPqrbUVyjfIQ6DDfmG9LHsvfZDQYeDMoBdx5lj0Zg_JPGtAXpRuDJLwur38bEhCFEFr83MOpm33acfRyVmnsGhSC5CKDCG0ff47mmeiYWMJvu31PiQ"), height: Optional(3264.0), width: Optional(4928.0), htmlAttributions: ["https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105919192065953018435/photos\">Nevruz Alievski"]), GooglePlaces.GooglePlaces.PlaceDetailsResponse.Result.Photo(photoReference: Optional("CoQBdwAAAOrw0v3gJ-95OvCQ0Vl2ouif3w25fjTOCYNdpDj8Z8ckrnv3VrB8GHWStp6-1JBMeYgDa9MUitmCuCqhUv_erlKL54PrzGMF1V6MlcxDVE69wOPiO8hGUqgVA9W43byzAexhmXm2zUKYcc5eSDVQsTVJK23pZpmszSsleYAM1irtEhCcTuT0vwUclqnC8S-Y7kByGhQr-pSAlgtsDDWSaO9x6zsTKtXncA"), height: Optional(960.0), width: Optional(1442.0), htmlAttributions: ["https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107721511037729767520/photos\">Thanathip Moolvong"]), GooglePlaces.GooglePlaces.PlaceDetailsResponse.Result.Photo(photoReference: Optional("CoQBdwAAAPp4uJgQmVn7i_IXQVEWigjncVXwK8sYvTJfN-rVk2eiUdlQa0YtrUJdi1zET-B-5Reh3E87WEHRYBSghgQFHF5NO3W9R1bz-gxvl3uSzKWJMqMLVHtFnB5tFRVzhtneuoS3-bJOKi6kBVxKgGqNweCt5wksrgq0N_BmU67f_ccqEhCd_HWij6-0084YzLWvU7znGhS_UtDNzjTt1tcyxM6mvid4V0_7Yw"), height: Optional(2741.0), width: Optional(4218.0), htmlAttributions: ["https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107141268018019653860/photos\">Yurii Moroz"]), GooglePlaces.GooglePlaces.PlaceDetailsResponse.Result.Photo(photoReference: Optional("CoQBdwAAAHL0HFMCIuYZEeQkW55TktH1iSGHp6t6Mq_lLZGPh0mFq33pP3J8EqpjagTrQ0cYmNLoC36nWaVgKxX-dFvTIUv1HDnqroNuUMP0XL1sjC7mNpVEQfoU745KXtyFyM0_fUH3XVBpQywZDtcRRpcdw0acog54oz1YBJcFi8bo0gn8EhC1KBpZk4wSeLAc8L-0q-nxGhQ4wmq77KyfzlHeIY0yzDWzaZ8r2g"), height: Optional(2988.0), width: Optional(5312.0), htmlAttributions: ["https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109188722990724442148/photos\">Carine Ianiro"]), GooglePlaces.GooglePlaces.PlaceDetailsResponse.Result.Photo(photoReference: Optional("CoQBdwAAABJ8XYRDc469OqDtMWQ_d1FBXdZlWBxDYZxLlv47u84VPRuubDxWjq5RQWJO1Exol0j2gWUdJJ6E6nRT8XCrqef7PRKrN9zBTYqZ98tnSA01Se7Av3YUo5ECv7feNOSYxIGcH4Mjth5xsgcUbj8G3z7lfKTmAp0EnHliupss69arEhAETE16c-eFUHmVz8ZPsdIlGhTKQRlgsl5-o090VJ8ZkPRqlwI5XA"), height: Optional(3024.0), width: Optional(4032.0), htmlAttributions: ["https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106687101859998441832/photos\">Christoffer Norén"])], placeID: Optional("ChIJ8fA1bTmyXEYRYm-tjaLruCI"), scope: Optional(GooglePlaces.GooglePlaces.PlaceDetailsResponse.Result.Scope.Google), alternativePlaceIDs: [], priceLevel: nil, rating: nil, reviews: [], types: ["country", "political"], url: nil, utcOffset: Optional(60), vicinity: nil, website: nil)), htmlAttributions: []))

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Where i don't fine please check where in question, in question where assigning value getting same also

Comment: yes that's ok but in variables it is correct and still getting same

Comment: ok .. that might be issue .. but I don't think so it should be same ... can you post your response

Comment: sure please check updated question

Comment: didn't got you yes it is giving same lat long in response

Comment: this value is in your response `GooglePlaces.GoogleMapsService.LocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 60.128161000000013, longitude: 60.128161000000013)` and both lat & long is same

Comment: yes so that is wrong response from google place api

Comment: may be yes .. but may be ... :)

Comment: that's my question, what now?

Comment: nothing .. just trust the google .. may be response is right as per place id

Answer (score 1):

In print statement your are printing `latitude` only in both print statement, print `longitude` correctly.

```
print("lat", response!.result!.geometryLocation!.latitude)
print("long",  response!.result!.geometryLocation!.longitude)
```

Thanks:)

Comment: That is only in print statement, if you check question properly i have mentioned google api response also.

Answer (score 1):

Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800803/unable-to-find-a-specification-for-googleplaces). Actually GooglePlace is deprecated and pod 'GooglePlacesAPI' need to use now.

Answer (score 0):

> Read the following link to resolve your issues.Use GoogleApiClient
>   instead of Google Places.

```
https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart
```